# How to prevent crash when selecting specific contact using AdressBookUI

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbookui

I'm getting crash on this line.

```
    phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, index));
```

If the first phone number is selected I get index of 1 which is wrong. It should be 0 and therefore choses wrong number. If I select second number it gives index of -1 which crashes the app.

```
#pragma mark helper methods

- (void)didSelectPerson:(ABRecordRef)person identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
    NSString *phoneNumber = @"";
    ABMultiValueRef numbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    if (numbers) {
        if (ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers) > 0) {
            CFIndex index = 0;
            if (identifier != kABMultiValueInvalidIdentifier) {
                index = ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(numbers, identifier);
            }
            phoneNumber = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, index));
        }
        CFRelease(numbers);
    }
    self.numberTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneNumber];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in iOS 8.3 (and presumably previous version of iOS 8) when working on copies of contacts that have had phone numbers/emails removed. The documentation for `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` states that:

> In iOS 8 and later bringing up a people-picker navigtion controller does not require the app to have access to a user’s contacts, and the user will not be prompted to grant access. If the app does not itself have access to the user’s contacts, a temporary copy of the contact selected by the user will be returned to the app.

In my testing I had a contact which had three phone numbers (let's call them `111`, `222` and `333`). It appears that `identifier`s are fixed, stable zero-based values. Thus my three phone numbers were identifier `0` to `2`. If a phone number is deleted the identifiers do not change. Zero-based `index`es are used to access the current list of phone numbers (or emails etc.) and `ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier` is used to convert an identifier into an index.

In my test I deleted the first phone number, `111`. This does not change the identifiers for the remaining phone numbers (`222=1`, `333=2`).

When I used `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and chose the first phone number (`222`) the delegate method `peoplePickerNavigationController: didSelectPerson:property:identifier:` correctly passed an identifier of `1`. However, `ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier` returned an index of 1, not 0 and my app then copied the phone number `333` as the one it thought the user had selected. If the user picked `333` then I was correctly passed an identifier of `2` but `ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier` converted that to `-1` and then an unprotected call to `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex` crashed.

So, when working on a *copy* of the contact (which is what happens in iOS 8 when the app has not been authorised to access the address book), iOS seems to be using identifiers based on the real contact, but indexes are based on the copy. The copy seems to have forgotten the previously-deleted phone number and the identifier-to-index mapping goes wrong if the user picks a phone number that was created after a previously-deleted phone number. It works if the user hasn't deleted phone numbers, or if they have deleted phone numbers *after* the one they pick.

The workaround is to complicate the app by making it ask the user for permission to access the Address Book using `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`. Once granted, the app will not be given a *copy* of the selected contact and the identifier-to-index mapping works correctly.

Comment: So is a potential solution to min/max bound the stable identifier to the number of items in the ABMultiValueRef, then extract the index from that? I suppose that doesn't guarantee you'd pick the correct number, though.

Comment: Correct. You'd potentially pick the wrong value then, which isn't a useful solution! For what it's worth iOS 9's new `CNContactPickerViewController` does seem to work correctly even without requiring permission to access the user's contacts (i.e. it works as documented, unlike `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`). Well, it did until about beta 4 when it started crashing for other reasons...

Comment: I tried the workaround you suggested and it didn't work for me. I am calling ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion but I am still getting the wrong index and nil when requesting the phone number.

Comment: @barisdad Are you sure the user granted permission to access the address book for your app? It's been a long time since I worked on my code, but that definitely fixed it for me. In iOS 9 I just use the Contact Framework instead (so my app supports both sets of calls depending on iOS version and only requests permission for the address book access on iOS 8 since the Contacts Framework works as documented)

Comment: I am sure the user granted permission since the user was me... :). Since I am using cordova I ended up selecting just the person via iOS and then designed my own UI to select a number. I checked it via an iphone 6s+ simulator.